# Getting lost in music while performing

Tags: piano, performing, stage-fright

When I am practicing alone (or in front of my parents), I always get lost in my music and in my own world (I play piano). However, when I practice in front of people I am uncomfortable with, I completely lose my bearings.

- Performing in front of my parents; totally fine- no stage fright
- Performing in front of a nice-looking person on the street (who I don't know); again, no stage fright and I can get lost in my music
- Performing in front of someone rather intimidating; I can't even focus, tons of stage fright

I'm asking because I have a competition soon (March 2023) and I have never played in front of an audience before (I've played on street pianos a few times but not in concert halls...or even an auditorium).

Any tips are welcome- thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I overcome the fear of performing in front of an audience?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/how-can-i-overcome-the-fear-of-performing-in-front-of-an-audience). Or https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/31045/tips-for-how-to-stay-calm-before-a-concert, or https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/106/what-are-good-tips-for-remaining-composed-during-ones-first-public-performance, or https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/82267/forgetting-the-musical-notes-while-performing-in-concert?rq=1

Comment: 1. Ideally you would have started performing earlier, but it's never too late.  2. Even famous concertizers can be plagued by this -- could be sometimes or always.  3. Have you tried a darkened small auditorium such that you can't see faces?